# Drag and drop picture to text and with double click to remove the text inside the box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Basic Drag and Drop</title>
<style>
#drop {
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px dashed #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: left;
}
p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#triangle {

  background: url(images/triangle.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#square {
  background: url(images/square.gif) no-repeat;
}
#circle {
  background: url(images/circle.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#red {
  background: url(images/red.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#yellow {
  background: url(images/yellow.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#green {
  background: url(images/green.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.drag {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  float: left;
  -khtml-user-drag: element;
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
<script>
var addEvent = (function () {
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    return function (el, type, fn) {
      if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
        el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
      } else if (el && el.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
        }
      }
    };
  } else {
    return function (el, type, fn) {
      if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
        el.attachEvent('on' + type, function () { return fn.call(el, window.event); });
      } else if (el && el.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
        }
      }
    };
  }
})();

(function () {

var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.id = "view-source"

// private scope to avoid conflicts with demos
addEvent(window, 'click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.hash == '#view-source') {
    // event.preventDefault();
    if (!document.getElementById('view-source')) {
      // pre.innerHTML = ('<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n' + document.documentElement.innerHTML + '\n</html>').replace(/[<>]/g, function (m) { return {'<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;'}[m]});
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      // original source - rather than rendered source
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          pre.innerHTML = this.responseText.replace(/[<>]/g, function (m) { return {'<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;'}[m]});
          prettyPrint();
        }
      };

      document.body.appendChild(pre);
      // really need to be sync? - I like to think so
      xhr.open("GET", window.location, true);
      xhr.send();
    }
    document.body.className = 'view-source';

    var sourceTimer = setInterval(function () {
      if (window.location.hash != '#view-source') {
        clearInterval(sourceTimer);
        document.body.className = '';
      }
    }, 200);
  }
});

})();
</script>

<style id="jsbin-css">

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="drag" id="triangle" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="drag" id="square" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="drag" id="circle" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="drag" id="red" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="drag" id="yellow" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="drag" id="green" draggable="true"></div>

  <div id="drop"></div>
<script>
function cancel(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return false;
}

var dragItems = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable=true]');

for (var i = 0; i < dragItems.length; i++) {
  addEvent(dragItems[i], 'dragstart', function (event) {
    // store the ID of the element, and collect it on the drop later on
    event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);




  });
}

var drop = document.querySelector('#drop');

// Tells the browser that we *can* drop on this target
addEvent(drop, 'dragover', cancel);
addEvent(drop, 'dragenter', cancel);
addEvent(drop, 'drop', function (e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); // stops the browser from redirecting off to the text.

  this.innerHTML += '<p>' + e.dataTransfer.getData('Text') + '</p>';
  return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

how to double click remove the text inside the textbox by using html5? I having problem on how to remove the text out from the textbox in this html5. things can be drag and drop inside, but i want to remove the things inside that i have been dragged inside... i having problem on removing the item inside that.

Comment: sorry for asking, fiddle means?

Comment: jsfiddle.net is a page where you can set your Javascript code

Answer (score -1):

Try using this.

```
document.getElementById('selectID').ondblclick = function(){
alert(this.selectedIndex);//remove your text here
};
```

Comment: sorry for asking that needed to put in below which line?

Comment: probably you will be having an id for textbox,using that take the control of that textbox and make (itsID.val='').U have to do this after drag and drop..Got it..

Comment: currently i am using the "this.id", can i ask how to change?

Comment: function() for removed text is ?

Comment: this.id.val='' or create another variable with empty value and pass it as this.id.val(variable);

Comment: still cant find the id, cause its  <div id="drop"></div> change to the "drop"

Comment: first make clear..you have some text inside the div.after drag and drop you want to remove that text from div.

Comment: yes... that true, now i having problem on how to remove that text from div after i drag and drop.

Comment: document.getElementById('drop').innerHTML = "";

Comment: document.getElementById('drop').innerHTML.ondblclick = function(){this.innerHTML=""); }; if i want to double click removed, is it like above one?

Comment: var a=document.getElementById('drop').ondblclick();a="";document.getElementById("drop").innerHTML=a;

Comment: document.getElementById('drop').ondblclick = function(){
this.innerHTML+="";//this will remove the whole text inside the box, but i one remove on selected text, how am i going to code?

Comment: if i want the selected text, not the whole text?